# Wicket: Changes to HTML or Java Source is not loaded when browser is refreshed

Tags: java, wicket, reload

I am following the Wicket user guide's "Hello World" project.

Wicket is in DEVELOPMENT mode.

When I change the HomePage.html and reload the browser, the change is not shown.  If I restart the WicketApplication, then the changes are shown.

My application is at localhost 8080

All my research shows that changes should be loaded automatically when the application is in DEVELOPMENT mode (which it is).

I have not changed any configuration from the default Wicket installation.

Comment: You can use [Jrebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) to force reloading of changed sources on the application server. It comes at a price, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found.

For the class reloading issue, I run the "Start" application through Debug mode in IntelliJ.  When in Debug mode, IntelliJ reloads classes that have changed.

For the HTML reloading issue, I put the following code in the WicketApplication init() method:

```
// add your configuration here
getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency( Duration.ONE_SECOND);
getResourceSettings().setDefaultCacheDuration(Duration.ONE_SECOND);

List list = new ArrayList();
list.add( new IResourceFinder() {
    @Override
    public IResourceStream find( Class<?> clazz, String pathname ) {
        File f = new File( "C:/MyProject/src/main/java/" + pathname );
        if ( f.exists() ) {
            return new FileResourceStream( f );
        }
        return null;
    }
} );

getResourceSettings().setResourceFinders( list );

getResourceSettings().setUseDefaultOnMissingResource(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

No, if you deploy your app into app-server (like tomcat, glassfish, etc.), then the real .html's that shows in browser located somewhere in app-server folders.

For glassfish it can be "/path_to_glassfish/glassfish/domains/domainXX/applications/APP_NAME/WEB-INF/classes/...".
So, even if you change .html's at your project, you must to redeploy this changes.

Wicket JavaDoc says :

> if the configuration type is DEVELOPMENT, resources are polled for
>   changes...

Yes, but is holds for resources located at appropriate folders. I think [this wicket forum thread](http://apache-wicket.1842946.n4.nabble.com/Resource-auto-reload-with-the-Quickstart-project-td3665329.html) will give you some answers of how to implements behavior you want. This post is actually for old wicket version, but I think it is suitable for newer versions too.

In our company we use [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/firebug/) or chrome console to stylize components right in browser without redeploying app, and this is enough for us, because static components rarely added on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different solution. Because I'm using Google App Engine, when I add the code 
getResourceSettings().setResourcePollFrequency( Duration.ONE_SECOND) to my application init() method, the application fails to load pages. It has something to do with the fact that App Engine does not support multiple threads. Because of this I had to find a different solution. Instead I decided that when I was in dev mode I would completely remove the MarkupCache. To do that, I needed to create a new cacheless MarkupFactory.

```
public class CachelessMarkupFactory extends MarkupFactory {

  @Override
  public IMarkupCache getMarkupCache() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasMarkupCache()
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then in the my WebApplication code, I set my new CachlessMarkupFactory as the default MarkupFactory.

```
@Override
protected void init()
{
    super.init();

    //in dev mode, disable markup cache
    if(isDevelopmentServer())
    {
        getMarkupSettings().setMarkupFactory(new CachelessMarkupFactory());
    }
}
```